# Disable several days in React big calendar event

Tags: reactjs, react-big-calendar

I am using react big calendar version 0.38.5. I searched a bit but couldn't find it. I want to do this. For example, I have an event between January 1, 2022 and January 25, 2022. I'm showing this on the react big calendar. I want to show that this event does not exist on January 17, 2022. Changing the color of that day is not a solution because if there is a different event that day, it may seem like it is not there. All I want is for that event to have a different color that day. How should I go about this?

in the example in the picture I want to make the 02 date of the blue event red
[image]

Comment: Your question confuses me. Does your event start on the 1st and end on the 25th? Or do you have the same event repeated in multiple slots (separate 'event' objects for each day)?

Comment: Yes, starting on January 1st and ending on January 25th, and only showing this event as if it didn't exist on January 17th.

Answer (score 0):

Based on response to your question, you cannot do what you ask. In Big Calendar, an 'event' is actually a div that is sized and positioned above the actual calendar cells. The only time it breaks up in to separate pieces is when it's span goes over another week, and even then each 'day' piece isn't identifiable.

You can style a 'day' cell or row (`dayPropGetter`), a 'slot' in the TimeGrid views (`slotPropGetter`), or an entire 'event' (`eventPropGetter`), but you can't break an 'event' up into multiple parts. Unless it spans across a boundary (like week to week in the 'month' view) it's just a single 'div'.